# python: importing csv to db using csv.DictReader results in an Error: DictReader instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I was trying for importing data from the csv file to the sqlite db using python script.

I have a DB table with the name NSETCS:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

with open (r'F:\mypractise_python\day11\NSE-TCS.csv','r') as infile:
    content = [csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')]  # read the whole file at once

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect('NSETCS')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    for line in content:
        date = line['Date']
        open_stock = float(line['Open'])
        high = float(line['High'])
        low = float(line['Low'])
        last= float(line['Last'])
        close= float(line['Close'])
        tot_trade_qt= float(line['TotTrQt'])
        turnover= float(line['Turnover (Lacs)'])
        cursor.execute('''insert into  NSETCS values (:date, :open_stock, :high, :low, :last, :close, :tot_trade_qt, :turnover)''',\
                       {'date':date, 'open_stock':open_stock, 'high':high, 'low':low, 'last':last, 'close':close,\
                     'tot_trade_qt':tot_trade_qt, 'turnover':turnover})

except Exception as E:
    print "Error:", E
else:
    db.commit()

db.close()
```

On running the code, I get an error: 
 Error: DictReader instance has no attribute `__getitem__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the contents into a list here:

```
content = [csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')]  # read the whole file at once
```

That only puts the reader into a list. Use `list()` instead:

```
content = list(csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=','))
```

Not that you need to do this; you could just loop over the object directly:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')
```

then

```
for line in reader:
```

Do indent the code that loops to be part of the `with` statement, because you need to keep the file open to read until the loop is done:

```
with open (r'F:\mypractise_python\day11\NSE-TCS.csv','r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')

    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect('NSETCS')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        for line in reader:
            # ...
```

I'd not catch exceptions; just [use the connection as a *context manager*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) (just like you do for the file) so that your inserts are committed only if no exceptions took place:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

db = sqlite3.connect('NSETCS')
# use both file and database connection as context managers
with open (r'F:\mypractise_python\day11\NSE-TCS.csv','r') as infile, db:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    for line in reader:
        line['turnover'] = line['Turnover (Lacs)']
        cursor.execute('''
            insert into  NSETCS values (
                :Date, :Open, :High, :Low, :Last, :Close, 
                :TotTrQt, :turnover)
            ''', line)
```

`sqlite` doesn't really care if you pass in `float()` objects, or `str()`; the database is happy to accept either for numeric columns. You can use your `line` dictionaries directly if you don't convert to `float()`, except for the `Turnover (Lacs)` column (I used an alias in the dictionary for that one). This simplifies your loop somewhat.

Comment: martijn, it's working good when i converted to content = list(csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=','))......I didn't understood the next part where you said I could just loop over the object.....wts that?

Comment: isn't the same i am doing in the 'for line in content' ?

Comment: @FarhanPatel: My apologies; I wrote this in a bit of a rush and forgot to remove the `list()` call. Looping can be done over the `csv.DictReader()` object without reading all contents into a list first.

Comment: removing the list() is not working in my case.....it's giving me I/O error

Comment: @FarhanPatel: ah, yes, because you need to indent the rest of your code to be part of the `while` statement. If you don't the file is already closed by the time you loop.

Comment: i guess u were suggesting me to indent the rest of the code as per the with open <..> statement:  that works great!!!....thnx

Comment: @FarhanPatel: I've further simplified the code somewhat.

Comment: @FarhanPatel: thanks for the correction; that's what you get when writing off-the-cuff without running it in the interpreter for testing first.

Comment: @FarhanPatel: no, the cursor was lost, back again.

Comment: @martjin, hey buddy also i guess we can call dynamic binding using db.execute instead of cursor.execute when we are using context manager, won't that work?...

Comment: You can; it'll use a new cursor under the hood. It's better to reuse a single cursor here though.